# Uso de Bootstrap em layout legado sem adoção de Grid system

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-glyphicons

Considere um layout complexo e legado, dependente de tables e que não pode ser convertido em tableless.

A partir desta premissa, se inseríssemos CSS e Javascript do Bootstrap,
conseguiríamos utilizar alguns componentes (como o Glyphicons ou Navbar) ou ainda CSS como o `.visible-*` sem adotar o `Grid system`?

Se sim, qual seria a versão mínima do Bootstrap para um caso como este?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, tranquilamente, na verdade, você pode customizar o bootstrap para utilizar somente o que você precisa, confere neste link:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Outra coisa interessante, é que ao baixar o pacote do boostrap, vai vir junto um arquivo chamado `config.json`, este arquivo permite que você edite o seu pacote customizado.

Para isto, é necessário uma conta no github, depois você cria um `gist`, que vai possuir um identificador igual a este:

https://gist.github.com/aymone/9a42d82c563979c0a5a2

Copie todo o conteúdo para o seu `gist` e nomeia ele como `config.json`.

Copie o identificador do `gist` que é os caracteres após a última barra:

```
`9a42d82c563979c0a5a2`
```

Então você pega este identificador do seu gist, criado com o conteúdo do arquivo config.json e passa ele como parâmetro `id` no link do bootstrap/customize desta forma:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/**?id=9a42d82c563979c0a5a2**

E voilá, seu arquivo customizado, carregado no site do bootstrap para remover ou adicionar os componentes e personalizações que você quiser novamente.

A idéia é customizar tudo direto no pacote, e minimizar a quantidade de `css` adicional.

Sobre a versão, recomendo a última, versão 3, mas com a 2 também funciona, apenas para seu código não ficar muito defasado.

Comment: Isto é muito, muito útil para fazer alterações no seu bootstrap, sem precisar configurar tudo denovo.

Comment: Obrigado @Marcelo Aymone! Meu pacote personalizado ficou em http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=726712b247d9e166caa9 e agora é mão na obra com isso. Um abraço!

Comment: Legal, use e abuse, é uma ótima ferramenta, tenho adotado bastante.